# Setting up application-level authentication on HTTP server with MarkLogic

Tags: authentication, marklogic, marklogic-9

I am trying to set up application-level authentication on an HTTP server using MarkLogic. After switching to application-level authentication in the Admin interface and setting the default user as an admin, I'm still getting an error message when using the `xdmp.login` function with a username and password for an admin user.

```
xdmp.login('username','password')
```

> [javascript] XDMP-APPREQ: xdmp.login("username", "password") -- Application level authentication required
>
> Stack Trace
>
> In undefined on line 3
>
> In xdmp.login("username", "password")

Comment: https://mlu.marklogic.com/ondemand/664e0cac

Comment: https://www.marklogic.com/blog/integrating-single-sign-on-solutions/